# Precompiled Azure Function and SOAP endpoints

Tags: azure, wcf, azure-functions, servicenow

I'm writing a precompiled Azure function that will perform a SOAP call to ServiceNow.  The code works as a standalone exe but I can't seem to get it converted to a precompiled function.  In know it's because my DLL can't find the app.config file but what's the best way to get around it.  Error message below.  ServiceNow requires I set certain bindings and endpoint configuration.  The other contractors for their ServiceNowSoapClient class allow me to specify a url directly but don't seem to allow me to get to the binding settings.

> Exception while executing function: Functions.TimerTriggerCSharp.
>   System.ServiceModel: Could not find endpoint element with name
>   'ServiceNowSoapDev' and contract 'ServiceNowReference.ServiceNowSoap'
>   in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be
>   because no configuration file was found for your application, or
>   because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the
>   client element.

Answer (score 1):

In WCF you can define your client binding and endpoint programmatically instead of using `app.config`. Use the constructor of the generated client with two parameters:

```
new ServiceNowSoapClient(binding, remoteAddress);
```

See more code [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647110.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: This worked; I added it programmatically and it's working.  Thanks